# Remove NSEntityDescription Objects from list of Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, automatic-ref-counting

I wanted to remove all my NSEntityDescription objects from core data and release the memory. the `reset` function doesn't make any difference to to the memory

following is my code

```
-(void)generatePersons: (NSManagedObjectContext *)privatecontext{
    self.persons = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [privatecontext performBlockAndWait:^{
        for(int i = 1; i< self.dataRows.count; i++){
            NSArray *HeaderRow = [self.dataRows objectAtIndex:1];
            NSArray *dataRow = [self.dataRows objectAtIndex:i];

            if (dataRow.count <=  HeaderRow.count){
                int index = 0;

                Person *person = (Person *)[NSEntityDescription
                                            insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person"
                                            inManagedObjectContext:privatecontext];



                [self.persons addObject:person];


            }
        }

        [privatecontext reset];

    }];
}
```

this code `[privatecontext reset];` theoretically set the context to its base state, in my understanding it will release the memory as well but it doesn't and remains at the same memory count

Comment: All those instances are still retained by your array.

Comment: @TomHarrington even if we comment this line `[self.persons addObject:person];` it still occupies the same amount of memory even after going out of the for loop scope and wait block scope

Answer (score 0):

Try using a weak reference to self in your block.

Create the reference before your block's inline declaration:

`__weak __block __typeof(&*self)weakself = self;`

Then use `weakself` instead of `self` there. That may be preventing the thread from releasing its memory.

Comment: you misunderstood the question.